# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error on axios request even after enabling express CORS middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am recently deployed my API on Heroku, and I'm having some CORS related issues. I've seen many other posts that  talk about enabling CORS (and I've done that in my code), but whenever I make the axios POST request, I still get the same error: `Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` I've also tried messing around with the configuration object for cors(), but nothing seems to work.

The actual post request from the frontend looks like this:

```
const axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      };
  await axios
    .post("https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/register", data, axiosConfig)
    .then((_) => Message.success("Successfully registered! "))
    .catch((error) => Message.error(error.message));
```

and my app.js on the backend looks like this.

```
const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(
  cors({
    allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"], // you can change the headers
    exposedHeaders: ["authorization"], // you can change the headers
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false,
  })
);

// set up different routers
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const registrationRouter = require("./registration/routes");
const retailRouter = require("./retail-info/routes");
const bookingRouter = require("./booking/routes");

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (file.originalname.startsWith("CODE_COVER_QLYag759")) {
      cb(null, "temp-storage/cover/");
    } else {
      cb(null, "temp-storage/");
    }
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); //Appending extension
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  // dest: "temp-storage/",
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // no larger than 5mb, change as needed.
  },
});

// view engine setup

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/register", upload.any(), registrationRouter);
app.use("/retail", retailRouter);
app.use("/booking", bookingRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err.message });
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, console.log(`MyApp backend started on port ${port}!`));

module.exports = app;
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, but could I get plausible explanations for why my current code doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I generally use CORS module for cross origin requests how ever below code also works fine of you dont't want to add cors

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Comment: I have already used the npm CORS module. Why isn't that working?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this before adding your routes

```
// every  response we send has these headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix my issue. I just added this, and ran git push heroku master. Still the same error.

Comment: The 'cors' module (and the usage by OP) is already doing what you are trying to add. This will not help.

Comment: Thanks! @RvyPandey Do you have any theories as to why this might not be working?

Comment: To start with, I have not tested your code, but '\*' is not a valid option as per the documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options. I also see down below in the docs that default value is '\*'. Is it possible for you to set a specific value to the origin? (or better use a function for origin: https://github.com/alexishevia/blogExamples/blob/cors/backend/app.js#L12 - to log and debug)

Comment: I have tried just using app.use(cors()), which should technically set the required access configurations, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting headers to allow as one of the answers suggest

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or, you can use a middleware `cors` package in node to do this. [CORS npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

`app.use(cors());`

https://auth0.com/blog/cors-tutorial-a-guide-to-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Or, you can use a `proxy` from where you're requesting in the client-side like this:

```
var proxy = https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/;
      await axios
        .post(proxy+"https://myapp-backend.herokuapp.com/register", data, axiosConfig)
        .then((_) => Message.success("Successfully registered! "))
        .catch((error) => Message.error(error.message));
```

Comment: As you can see, I indeed used cors(). It's still not working.

Comment: Did you try the last approach as well?

Comment: I will try it now, but why aren't the other approaches working? I referred to the documentation and I don't see what's different.